# Como enviar parametros select-option dentro de un formulario a una funcion con react

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de capturar de un componente select; que se encuentra dentro de un formulario, la opcion que seleccione el usuario para enviarlo a una funcion que me dispare un proceso sql utilizando dicha opcion seleccionada.
Acontinuacion les muestro el codigo del formulario:

```
<ListaAreas isOpen={isOpenModal1}  closeModal={closeModal1}> 
        <center>
            <div style={{width:"90%"}}>
                <form onSubmit={()=>EnviarDatos(data.value)}>
                    <h3>Seleccione el Area a Procesar</h3>
                        <Select
                            options = {data.map(sup=>({label:sup.Locatio,value:sup.Locatio}))}
                            onChange= {handleSelectChange}
                        />    
                        <br></br>
                        <button type="submit"> Ejecutar </button>
                </form>    
            </div>
        </center>
        </ListaAreas>
```

Y por otro lado les anexo la funcion que deseo, obtenga(pueda leer) la opcion y lo utilice para la ejecucion del proceso sql:

```
const EnviarDatos = function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        const valor = e.Locatio;
        console.log('Este es el parametro con el que mandamos a ejecutar el proc en sqlserver :',valor);

    }
```

Tambien me estoy auxiliando de otra funcion que me permite leer la opcion seleccionada del componente Select, esto unicamante me muestra cual opcion he seleccionado del Select:

```
const handleSelectChange = function(selectedOption) {
    
    const opcion = selectedOption.value;
    //setData(opcion);
    console.log("Seleccionastes :",opcion);
    //--En esta funcion necesito llamar a la ejecucion del proceso
    
}
```

Esta ultima funcion auxiliar si funciona, el problema como se los explicaba al inicio, consiste en hacer click al boton de ejecutar, que es en donde no he logrado leer el valor seleccionado para que me lo muestre en esta (EnviarDatos); entonces, como hacer para que pueda leerlo y utilizarlo en esa misma funcion.

El formulario es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano por su tiempo y quedo a la espera por su valiosa ayuda.

Comment: Gracias g.4. tu respuesta fue muy acertada....

Comment: Que bien, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que verificar que se puede ver el valor del `option`al seleccionarlo:

```
const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
    //aqui deberías ver el valor del option seleccionado
    console.log(event.target.value)
};
```

Si lo muestra en consola, se puede hacer lo siguiente.

Crear un estado para manejar el `select` al inicio del componente:

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');
```

Al seleccionar alguna opción se va a actualizar el valor del estado `selectedValue`:

```
 const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
    // actualizar el valor del estado selectedValue
    setSelectedValue(event.target.value);
  };
```

Finalmente se consume el último valor seleccionado de `selectedValue` dentro de `EnviarDatos`:

```
const EnviarDatos = function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        //aqui se usa el valor del estado, el ultimo seleccionado 
        const valor = selectedValue;
        console.log('Este es el parametro con el que mandamos a ejecutar el proc en sqlserver :',valor);

}
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: procedi con tus recomendaciones de la siguiente manera (colocare unicamente las diferencias):                                                                                                          
    const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
        setSelectedValue(event.value);
        console.log(event.value);
    }

Comment: const EnviarDatos = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const valor = selectedValue;
        console.log('Este es el valor con el que se ejecutara el proceso',valor);
    }                                                                                                                                     Practicamente la diferencia esta en la funcion handleSelectChange en donde cambio de (event.target.value) por (event.value), por lo demas quedo chulada, ahora ya puedo proceder con le invocacion a mi proceso almacenado.                         Infinitas Gracias